# How to make a default filter value in list page, dynamic data websites?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-dynamic-data

In a dynamic data website there is a list page load table data which contain a Date field, I want to filter data by this column on page load, for example to show Just today date records in the grid, how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Where clause on the Page_init method of List.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    table = DynamicDataRouteHandler.GetRequestMetaTable(Context);
    defaultValues = Page.GetFilterValuesFromSession(table, table.GetColumnValuesFromRoute(Context));
    GridView1.SetMetaTable(table, defaultValues);

    switch (table.Name)
    {
        case "Employees":
            GridDataSource.Where = "EndDate >= DateTime.Now";
            break;
```

etc